# Pipe and I/O Redirection in C

Tags: c, operating-system

Please consider the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define READ 0
#define WRITE 1

int fd[2];

void execute(char*[], int mode);

int main()
{
char * command1[3] = {"cat", "output.txt", NULL};
char * command2[3] = {"wc", "-l", NULL};

pipe(fd);                       // creating pipe...


execute(command1, WRITE);               // execute command1 and write output to pipe
execute(command2, READ);                // execute command2 and get output from pipe


return 0;
}

//....................... DEFINATION .......................

void execute(char* command[], int mode)
{
pid_t pid;

pid = vfork();
if(pid == 0)
{
    if(mode == WRITE)               // writes successfully to the pipe...
    {
        close(1);
        dup(fd[WRITE]);
        close(fd[READ]);
        close(fd[WRITE]);

        execvp(command[0], command);
    }

    else if(mode == READ)               // doesnot read from the pipe and goes to the wait state...
    {
        close(0);
        dup(fd[READ]);
        close(fd[WRITE]);
        close(fd[READ]);

        execvp(command[0], command);
    }
}

else if(pid > 0)
{
    wait(NULL);
}

}
```

I am trying to write a program that uses pipe with stdout from first process being redirected as the stdin for the second process. But I am facing a problem. The code above executes the first command "command1" and write data to the pipe successfully. But second command "command2" doesn't read data from the pipe and goes to some kind of wait/block state. I don't know what the problem is. If the writing to pipe is done successfuly then why reading from pipe is unsuccessful?

A help would highly be appriciated. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: man vfork: *The vfork() function has the  same  effect  as  fork(2), except that the behavior is undefined if the process created by vfork() either modifies any data other than a variable of type  pid_t  used  to store  the  return  value from vfork(), or returns from the function in which vfork() was called, or calls any other function  before  successfully calling _exit(2) or one of the exec(3) family of functions.* Why would you *ever* use `vfork()` nowadays?

Comment: @EOF It is efficient, doesnot copy the address space of the parent process. If you want to perform exec() operation in child, it is best practice to use vfork... Anyways I also used the fork command, it gave the same result...

Comment: You may think `vfork()` is more "efficient", but it is also harder to use correctly. In particular, you are *not* using it correctly, and consequently your program exhibits *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Nowadays, vfork is not so much more efficient than fork (fork have been optimized since many years). vfork is just considered as obsolete.

Comment: If you do happen to run into problems with vfork, the most efficient (runtime, not programmer time) way to do a fork-and-exec nowadays is likely [posix_spawn](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/posix_spawn.html).

Comment: Don't use `dup`; use `dup2`.  `dup2(fd[WRITE], STDOUT_FILENO);` accomplishes `close(STDOUT_FILENO); dup(fd[WRITE]);` but does not rely on `STDOUT_FILENO` being the smallest-numbered unused fd. Unix added `dup2` for a reason, decades ago.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick OMG, what a crazy function! It includes a *de facto* virtual machine for running a language of "file actions".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the parent didn't close the WRITE part of the pipe, the reader is blocked waiting for data that will never come (parent is waiting for his blocked child).

Just add a call to `close(fd[WRITE]);` in between the call to your `execute` function.

Becareful to always close unused ends of pipes...

You may also not call `wait` this way (your subprocesses executes one after each other), move the call to `wait` after calls to `execute` (call wait twice).